# Add new div / element by jquery but there is no ID / class div parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problem to add new div element with jquery but there is no id / clas in div parent.

for the example i want to add new div element before `<img>`, this img have not id/class, also div parent.

my question is, how to create like that with jquery?

thanks all :)

[image]

Comment: So add a class or id to the HTML...? You could find the div by index or ordinal position in the document, but that is not very robust and will be very easy to break.

Comment: the problem is div element is from third party. I use mylivechat to show widget div, and i want to force add some elemet in it widget div

Comment: In that case wrap it in a containing div with a class or id, and traverse the DOM from there to find the element you need. It's still not robust as it will be broken if the HTML of the 3rd party plugin changes, but at least changes you make will not break it.

Comment: You can use `var img = $('.inpagebase').next().find('img')` or `$('.inpagebase').next().prepend(newDiv)`, but who knows: maybe there will appear `div` between them, and code will break down.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no unique identifier like `id` there are still other selector methods you can use.  You can use sibling selectors or traverse the DOM.  if the markup is consistent, you can do something like this

```
$('.inpagebase + div img').before(nodeToInject);
```

that's just one way to do it.  I'd look into DOM traversal with jQuery or CSS sibling selectors.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nth child selector to append div.

according to example image you are trying to append new div inside 2nd div in body.

```
<script>
 $(function(){
   $( "body div:nth-child(2)" ).append( "<div> your content </div>" );
 });
</script>
```

This will place new div inside 2nd div from body tag. [find jquery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)